# I emailed a law and data privacy professor regarding an issue I was having to do with internet privacy law. Will I get in legal trouble for this?

Tags: united-states, internet, data-protection, email

I emailed an American law and data privacy professor to ask to help explain whether google could reveal my information if a court order was taken out to identify me. I was very over emotional in the email saying things like “what’s going to happen to me?” They didn’t respond as this was Dec 19th however later on I realised what an idiot I was for emailing them something that I knew already was a small problem and apologised for wasting their time on such trivial matters. Then I emailed them another apology asking for their forgiveness blaming my anxiety on my impulsive decision and the way I overreacted to the situation. Could I get into legal trouble for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could I get into legal trouble for this?

No. Relax. Your three emails are very unlikely to cause a data privacy professor to feel harassed. Just move on regardless of whether he replies at all. Don't keep sending another email just because the recipient has not replied to your previous one.

As for the issue that prompted you to start emailing the professor, what everyone else has told you is correct. And the other email user is unlikely to take court action for something like this. The effort and cost of drafting & filing suit, and then pursuing discovery would dissuade most people unless they are incurring actual losses (which is not the case with your messages). Just move on so that this other user also can move on.